# Symfony get parameters from config files in the controllers

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using [Symfony 4.4](https://symfony.com/) with [swiftmailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html).

I have this configuration in the `dev/swiftmailer.php`

```
$container->loadFromExtension
(
   'swiftmailer',
    [
       'delivery_addresses' =>
            [
                'test@gmail.com',
            ],
        'url' => $mailHostname,
        'port' => $mailPort
    ]
);
```

But I'am not able to get the setting information from my controller:

```
public function XController(ContainerBagInterface $containerBag)
{
$containerBag->has("swiftmailer.mailer.default.delivery_addresses"); //this return true;
$containerBag->has("swiftmailer.mailer.default.url"); //this return false;
```

Why the second assert return false and the value is not set by the config file?

Answer (score 1):

The [URL parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#url) contains the entire SwiftMailer configuration using a DSN-like URL format. After constructor used it to configure your mailer instance, this value is unset to avoid security issues and expose your password.

Because of the name of the variable `$mailHostname`, I guess you should use the [host parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#host) instead of `url`.

```php
$container->loadFromExtension
(
   'swiftmailer',
    [
       'delivery_addresses' =>
            [
                'test@gmail.com',
            ],
        'host' => $mailHostname,
        'port' => $mailPort
    ]
);
```

I tested it, and this is my result:

```php
public function XController(ContainerBagInterface $containerBag)
{
$containerBag->has("swiftmailer.mailer.default.delivery_addresses"); //this returns true;
$containerBag->has("swiftmailer.mailer.default.url"); //this always returns false;
$containerBag->has("swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.smtp.host"); //but this returns true now;
```

Comment: I have the same problem: `The parameter "swiftmailer.mailer.default.host" must be defined.`

Comment: I have understood: The parameter is `swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.smtp.host`
But I don't know the reason.

Comment: Because a mailer can have different transport (smtp, gmail, sendmail, null)

Comment: I have thought that there is a relation one to one with the conf file and the string (swiftmailer.mailer.default.host). I have noted that I have to use the Symfony command in order to have all the parameters `php bin/console debug:container --parameters`

Comment: @yalabef21 That would be an example of wrong thinking though it is a common mistake.  In Symfony the configuration file is processed in a compile phase.  The bundle has the option of converting some config vales into parameters but it is not required.  For the most part, the configuration processor will inject the values directly where they are needed.  The docs provide details. "bin/console debug:container --parameters" will show you exactly which parameters are defined.